# Different license files for different languages in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have multi language install file created in Inno Setup. How I can use different license file for different language?

For example:
English language -> English license
Russian language -> Russian license

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want a custom licence for each language, you can use specify the [`LicenceFile`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_languagessection.htm#licensefile) parameter on the `[Languages]` entry.

If you want to show two seperate licences, you will need to add `[Code]` to do this yourself, using the `CreateOutputMsgMemoPage()` function, and loading the other licence file using somethign like:

```
ExtractTemporaryFile('additional licence.txt');
LoadStringFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}/additional licence.txt'), LicenceText);
LGPLPage.RichEditViewer.RTFText := LicenceText;
```

If you want a seperate set of Agree/don't agree buttons, you'll also need to create and add these to the page and enabled/disable the `WizardForm.NextButton` as required.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and your answer (from Deanna) help me to solve. Thank you! 
Even so I had some dificult.
I did not understand the MessagesFile was parameter to [Languages]

So I am post the example, to complete the friend answer:

```
[Languages]
Name: "en";   MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl";                       LicenseFile: "doc\file-en.rtf"
Name: "ptb";  MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\BrazilianPortuguese.isl"; LicenseFile: "doc\file-ptb.rtf"
Name: "es";   MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Spanish.isl";             LicenseFile: "doc\file-es.rtf"
```